# Уведомления на C# (ЮМани)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, архитектура, уведомления, яндекс-касса

Есть проект который работает с Яндекс Кассой, она же теперь ЮМани. При совершенной оплате и изменении статуса платежа ЯК высылает уведомление об этом. У меня есть проект который работает только с ЯК и в зависимости от проекта который запрашивал создание платежа, отправляет ему уведомление. Отправка происходит через планировщик (использую Coravel). Каждую минуту он чекает БД на наличие измененных записей которые не доставлены нужному проекту, создает очередь отправки и по каждой записи отправляет уведомление на проект. Если доставлено удаляет из очереди запись, иначе оставляет и увеличивает счетчик попыток доставки уведомления на единицу.

Хотел глянуть реализации у других людей нечто подобного и посмотреть другие варианты и выбрать более оптимальный.

Есть какие то идеи, ссылки или практики как сделать это лучше или быть может мысли?

В частности меня интересует как лучше отправлять такие уведомления, поочередно или многопоточно, поочередно вытягивать каждую запись из БД и уже потом отправлять или же брать разом все записи и циклично отправлять каждое уведомление в нужное место, целесообразно создавать подобную очередь или же достаточно просто чекать БД на наличие измененных статусов уведомления которые были недоставлены. Что лучше предусмотреть и реализовать на случай падения такого проекта, что нужно предусмотреть и реализовать при восстановлении такого проекта, как часто стоит чекать БД и отправлять уведомления - минута это много или мало, какое время будет более оптимально для подобного, стоит ли вообще оставлять счетчик попыток доставки уведомлений, сколько этих попыток нужно, или же ограничить по времени, если по времени то на какой промежуток, стоит ли скомбинировать эти 2 способа вместе, нужно ли делать ручной запрос к ЯК на запросы о статусах платежей, опять же когда, где, как часто, в каких случаях?

Искал в инете хотя бы по крупицам подобную инфу чтобы потом в общую картину оформить, но так толкового не нашел ничего. Поскольку опыта у меня не много, решил спросить у более опытных и продвинутых что и как будет лучше сделать с отправкой таких уведомлений, может кто то имеет подобное понимание и представление как лучше сделать и поделиться опытом, ну или может ссылками и статьями. Интересует любая инфа которая может помочь в подобной ситуации

Comment: Это вопрос на архитектуру - раз, возможно на [инспекцию кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/code-review/info) - два. Не думаю, что найдётся много участнико, кто работал с кассой, вероятно советы будут исходя из общих соображений. Например, почему вы не работаете по модели подписки? Проект который хочет получить уведомление может попросить проект который знает о поступлении платежа сразу и подписаться. Если у вас проект получающий инфу о поступлении оплаты работает по событию (а не по расписанию) это упростит архитектуру, не? Касса может вас уведомить сама или вы сами постоянное чекаете?

Comment: Да мне хотя бы общие соображения, потому что на проекте я 1 и больше никого, помощи просить банально не у кого, а сделать надо и сделать как следует.
Проект работает по подписке и ожидает от ЯК уведомлений по статусу платежей, но и как только его получает обрабатывает, заносит инфу в БД и передает планировщику который потом отправляет на проект который запрашивал создание платежа. Тут вопрос о том стоит ли запрашивать дополнительно вручную проекту статусы, когда и при каких обстоятельствах и как часто соответственно. ну и по перечислению того что я написал выше.